# How Java Language Works

Tags: java, jvm

My knowledge of Java isn't great, so I want to ask how the language works. By which I mean not just the "*Language*" but the Virtual Machine as well.

Here is my understanding.

1. Java compiler turns code into Java Byte-Code. in the form of a .java file
2. when the file is run, the JVM reads (just in time) the byte-code and turns it into machine code.
3. Computer reads the machine code and the program appears to run like a compiled program (to the user).

Is this hopelessly wrong?

Comment: Java bytecode files are `.class` files... `.java` are the source files.

Comment: Sounds about right (with `s/\.java/\.class/`), but is this the whole question?

Comment: hopeless not, it's more or less ok. JVM is way more complicated than just simple read byte code/turn into machine code. It optimizes, profiles and does code modification on-the-fly, if need be.

Comment: You've got the jist of it.  The compiler typically takes a `.java` (source code, in text) file and produces one or more `.class` file which contain the bytecode for each class defined in the source file.  The hardware has no idea whether it's running code from a compiled or interpreted language.  By the time the computer executes it, it's **all** machine code.

Comment: _Java compiler turns code into Java Byte-Code. in the form of a **.class** file_

Comment: oops, i guess comment don't refresh automatically like answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already many answers, but I'm missing one important point:

> "2. when the file is run, the JVM reads (just in time) the byte-code and turns it into machine code."

This is not quite correct.

- The JVM starts by **interpreting** the code
- It looks at the most time consuming parts, the **hot spots**
- It analysis the **traces**, i.e., the typical execution flow
- It generates machine code **optimized for the hot spots and the traces**

The less time-consuming parts of code may stay interpreted. If the situation changes (e.g., by loading a new class), some compiled code may show to be not optimal anymore or even incorrect, and it gets thrown away and the JVM reverts to interpreting for a while, then it re-compiles it again.

Answer (score 2):

A Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is the software, which interprets compiled Java byte code and runs the java program. **Java Virtual Machine language conceptually represents the instruction set of a stack-oriented, capability architecture.**

Java Virtual Machine does not have any information regarding the programming languages. JVM knows only binary byte code format. Programmer can generate the bytecode that adheres to this format in any of the programming languages. Every java program runs within the boundaries defined by the Java Virtual Machine.

The code of java runs inside the JVM cannot go beyond the security constraints defined by Java Virtual Machine. Java applications are considered as secure applications on internet due to this software.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. I'd like to add the below

1. The [HotSpot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html) compiler also **adaptively** compiles Java bytecodes into **optimized** machine instructions

Answer (score 0):

Almost:

- the Java compiler creates .class files not .java files, which contain the byte code. .java files contain the source code.
- the JVM (Java virtual machine) is like a (virtual) computer on its own. It interpretes the byte code. The OS only runs the JVM.
- A JIT (just in time) compiler can compile part of the code to machine code for performance reasons, in which case the JVM delegates the execution of that code to the OS (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

To be precise,

- When you create a java class, the extension would be .java
- During compilation, the compiler converts the code (.java file) to
  .class (byte code).
- When the code is run, JVM converts the byte code (.class file) to
  Machine code that can be interpreted by the OS. By doing so, it makes
  Java as platform independent and JVM as platform dependent.